# Heatmap for tables where entries are intervals

Tags: tables

I have a booktabs table like this.

```
\begin{table*}[h!]
  \centering
  \resizebox{\textwidth}{!} {\begin{tabular}{lccccc}
    Corr  &  a & b & c & d & e \\
    \midrule
    a & 0 & $.4 \pm .7$ & $.2 \pm .3$ & $.7 \pm .3$ & $.7 \pm .6$\\
    b & $.4 \pm .7$ & 0 & $.2 \pm .1$ & $.8 \pm .6$ & $.5 \pm .6$\\
    c & $.2 \pm .3$ & $.2 \pm .1$ & 0 & $.7 \pm .5$ & $.9 \pm .7$\\
    d & $.7 \pm .3$ & $.8 \pm .6$ & $.7 \pm .5$ & 0 & $.8 \pm .7$\\
    e & $.7 \pm .6$ & $.5 \pm .6$ & $.9 \pm .7$ & $.8 \pm .7$ & 0\\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
```

I want the table to be colored according to the mean value in the each entry. And I would like to display these intervals in the new heatmap table. I found this resource to create heatmaps but the heatmaps want a number and not an interval. So I am pretty stuck right now.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! You shouldn't use `\resizebox` with tables, as this leads to inconsistent font sizes, and possible tables  quite hard to read.

Comment: also `table*` is for tables spanning two columns which can not be placed `h` so `\begin{table*}[h!]` will force the table to the end of document (or `\clearpage`)

Comment: Oh ok. Thank you.